# solr fq without specifying field

Tags: solr

I am getting unexplainable results doing filtered query.

when entering "searchstring" into fq w/o specifying field and got a lot of hits. The schema.xml sets the "content" field as the default search field. However, the returned results is different when I enter content:"searchstring". Rather, it is the same if I enter url:"searchstring".

How did solr get configured to use url as the default fq search field? I checked into schema.xml but can not figure out how this was set.

does any one know?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely in your solrconfig.xml as default field. Just to be sure which field the fq is searching by default in your environment, run the query with debug=true option and in the debug response you will see an entry with "parsed_filter_queries". This will provide actual field on which it is filtering.